# Controller/Action not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have my action available. Multiple people work on this application and there is a chance that the buttons are clicked at the same time. Occasionally i get the following exception, how can i fix this?

**Exception**

```
System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'CorrectAsIsControl' was not found on controller 'Intranet.Site.Areas.OngoingProjects.Controllers.PaperSurveyEmailCleanUpController'.
Generated: Mon, 30 Jul 2012 21:38:49 GMT

System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): A public action method 'CorrectAsIsControl' was not found on controller 'Intranet.Site.Areas.OngoingProjects.Controllers.PaperSurveyEmailCleanUpController'.
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HandleUnknownAction(String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.AsyncController.<>c__DisplayClass19.<BeginExecuteCore>b__15()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.AsyncController.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.AsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.AsyncController.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

**Action:**

```
[HttpPost]
        [NoCaching]
        public ActionResult CorrectAsIsControl()


[HttpPost]
        [NoCaching]
        public ActionResult UnreadableControl()
```

**NoCaching Filter**

```
public partial class NoCaching : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        #region OVERRIDES


        public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
        }


        #endregion
    }
```

**Ajax Post**

```
_performStaticActions: function ($click) {
        var id = $click.attr("rel");
        var link = $click.attr("href");
        if (id == "")
            jMessageError("Unable to find Id, operation aborted!", $click, false, true);
        else if (link == "")
            jMessageError("Unable to find action link, operation aborted!", $click, false, true);
        else {
            jMessage("Processing request...", $click, true, false);

            //link = link + "?badEmailId=" + id;
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: link,
                type: Ajax.MethodType.POST,
                data: { badEmailId: id},
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    jMessageError(xhr.responseText, $click, false, true);
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.IsError) {
                        jMessageError(result.Message, $click, false, true);
                    } else {
                        jMessageOK(result.Message + "<br><br>Picking new item...", $click, false, false);
                        setTimeout('PaperSurveyBadEmailCleanUp._pickNewItem()', 3000);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Silly question, but those action methods are definitely in a controller called "PaperSurveyEmailCleanUpController"?

Comment: Yes. :) 
It happens occasionally and only on IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken out NoCaching attribute on ajax post actions and it seems to work. I haven't received any errors since yesterday. Now i need to rethink about the NoCaching attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent post by Phil Haack where he describes the use of a tool "Route Debugger" which is useful in scenario like yours here is the link http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/25/finding-bad-controllers.aspx

Comment: This happens occasionally and only on IE8.